# Regex transform for Java code with Notepad++ - date .format to SimpleDateFormat

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to do some re-factoring on my Java code. I need to turn this:
`X.format("Z")`

into this:
`(new SimpleDateFormat("Z").format(X))`

Examples:

`dateStart.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")` into
`(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(dateStart))`

`reportStart.format("yyyy-MM")` into
`(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM").format(reportStart))`

I'm thinking to use Notepad++ find/replace, but I'm not good with Regex, and hoping someone would know easily?

I've tried variations of the below, and the closest I've got is with the one below... But with the one below, it wants to take everything to the left of .format and treat that as $1

find:`([^)]*)\.format\(([^)]*)\)` replace with:
`(new SimpleDateFormat($2.format($1))`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). now when you’re refactoring anyway is a very good time to do the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a simple find / replace will work like this :

Find `(?s)(\w+)\.format\((.*?)\)`

**update**  Escape the parenthesis when used as literals because Boost::regex uses these characters as special operators in the replacement, format string.

`Boost-Extended format strings treat all characters as literals except for '$', '\', '(', ')', '?', and ':'`

Replace `\(new SimpleDateFormat\($2\).format\($1\)\)`

https://regex101.com/r/f77yBt/1

If interested in why certain characters need to be escaped to be considered
literals, see this :
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html

Essentially, boost::regex uses these characters to implement a pseudo-callback
that does simple (possibly nested) conditionals checking if a group matched
and taking a `yes : no` replacement action.

Answer (score 1):

#### Be aware that in Notepad++ the parenthesis have to be escaped in the replacement part.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\w+)\.format\((.+?)\)`
- Replace with: `\(new SimpleDateFormat\($2\).format\($1\)\)`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\w+)           # group 1, 1 or more word characters
\.              # a dot
format\(        # literally
(.+?)           # group 2, 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
\)
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: It was NP++ decision to use _only_  the boost extended format string syntax. Where the the default is `format_perl` and others boost::regex makes available to regex\_replace and the match\_results methods include format\_perl, format\_all (used), format\_sed and format\_literal. Why make it a point to say the parenthesis are special characters in the format string, why not just quote from the boost::regex website on what it is `Boost-Extended format strings treat all characters as literals except for '$', '\', '(', ')', '?', and ':'.` ? And more importantly why it is ?